# How to number each row returned from mysql as they are returned

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count

So What I want to do is to echo 1 for the first row that is returned and two for the 2nd one and so one, Please I just don't know how to phrase this, I don't want to just count rows from mysql table, I want to give each row a number automatically and echo that number.

Please forgive my deprecated code.

```
$log = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $columnid = '$id'") or die (mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($log)){
    echo row['name'];
}
```

Lets assume that the above returns some names. so I want this.
    1 : John
    2 : Nancy
    3 : Dave

I don't want to write those number.

Please take into account ORDER by rate DESC since I'm using that to descent the number by the biggest number of rate.

Comment: This isn't a great question, as it has nothing to do with mysql but more to do with programming logic, like adding a count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
$count = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($log)){
    echo $count . ' ' . row['name'];
    $count++;
}
```

Or:

```
echo '<ol>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($log)){
    echo '<li>' . row['name'] . '</li>';
}
echo '</ol>';
```

Comment: Good use of `<ol>` here, since this seems to really be a display concern rather than a data concern. That is, of course, if the output medium is, in fact, HTML.

Comment: Also don't forget that one could do `for ($count = 1; $row = mysql_fetch_array($log); $count++) ...`

Answer (score 0):

```
$log = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $columnid = '$id'") or die (mysql_error());
$c = 0
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($log)){
    echo row['name'];
    $c = $c + 1;
}
echo "Raw Count = ".$c
```